# Is there a standard REST API for DBus communication?

Tags: application-development

I've found [this](https://github.com/joshtronic/python-dbus-rest-server/blob/master/dbus-rest.py), but I'm trying not to borrow code for my application.

The reasoning is that if you're writing a local HTML5 App, you may want to call some DBus api from javascript(like ubuntuone for example).

Comment: Why do you need a REST API?  Why not use the standard DBus API?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why a desktop application would need this, the python-dbus API works well enough

Comment: HTML5 local application so you could talk to DBus from JS

Comment: Does this have to run in a browser, or in a simple Gtk/Webkit app?

Comment: Ideally it would run in a browser, but Gtk/Webkit would be sufficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My recommendation would be to use the HTML5 Quickly template. It is not yet released, and I will ask mhall to post where the code is, but the template combines together the power of HTML5 and Python.

This means you can talk to DBUS via Python, and trigger those methods using HTML5, which it seems you want to do.

- [The quickly HTML template is on launchpad here.](https://launchpad.net/quickly-community-templates)
- [reference](http://www.reddit.com/r/ubuntuappshowdown/comments/v40ws/app_obj_terrain_generator_based_on_realworld/c53n21h)

Comment: Quickly is dead - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/quickly/+bug/1494345